# NFA for binary words that do not end in 10

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

> Construct an NFA over $\{0, 1\}$ whose language contains only words that do not end with $10$.

This is one of the first problems in the book, so it's supposedly easy. I just can't figure it out. It's easy using a DFA, but I'm not so sure using an NFA. Maybe I'm not understanding a particular concept in the NFA.

Comment: Every DFA is also an NFA.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus you should make that an answer.

Comment: Presumably you mean "...whose language is the set of strings that do not end with 10."

Comment: I presume you mean an NFA over the alphabet $\{0,1\}$, which recognizes a language that is a subset of $\{0,1\}^*$.

Answer (score 5):

Every DFA is also, in particular, an NFA. Therefore if you have constructed a DFA for some language, then you have a fortiori constructed an NFA for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are more comfortable with regular expressions, try to define your language as one.

> For example $(0 + 1)^*(00 + 01 + 11) + 1 + 0 + \varepsilon$

Now convert the regular expression into an automaton with the simple method (which I assume you know).

Comment: This method won't give you pretty automata, but always correct ones (barring technical mistakes). You can always determinise and minimise afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Create one that accepts strings over $\{0,1\}^*$ that end with the suffix $00$, another one for strings that end with $01$, and a third one for strings that end with $11$ then take their union.[image: NFA accepting strings over {0, 1}* not ending with 10]

**EDIT** Now NFA handles strings whose length $\lt 2$ and has an initial state.

Comment: (1) Your diagram does not specify the initial state.  (2) You forgot to handle strings whose length is less than two.

Comment: Now the NFA in your diagram accepts all strings.